# The object name <TableName> contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql, sybase, rapidsql

I am trying to pull records from two tables in different servers using single query.
I am using the below format in select query .... but all i get is the above error.

is there a way i can pull records from two servers in single query like

```
select * from server1.db1.schema1.table1 s1,server2.db2.schema2.table2 s2 where s1.col1 = s2.col2
```

i am using sybase  and rapidsql.

EDIT: i am using Sybase Adaptive server enterprise 15.5 and rapid SQL 8.1.0

Comment: What Sybase database and version are you using?  ASE, IQ, SQL Anywhere?

Comment: i am using Sybase Adaptive server enterprise 15.5 and rapid SQL 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a syntax error, is that Sybase ASE can not reference external databases and tables that way for queries.  Queries only support the syntax `DATABASE.OWNER.TABLE` or `DATABASE..TABLE`.

With Sybase ASE you can query across multiple servers using [Component Integration Services (CIS)](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1550/html/omni_ug/title.htm).  This allows you to setup proxy tables or proxy databases that pull data that resides on a remote server.  The remote server needs to be added to the local server using [`sp_addserver`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1550/html/omni_ug/title.htm), and should either be in the interfaces/sql.ini or accessible via LDAP.

From there you have to add the login information for the remote server using [`sp_addexternalogin`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/CJGCAGHI.htm)

Next you will have to connect to the remote server, and define your proxy tables or proxy databases.

Once you have completed that, you can treat the proxy tables/databases as local to your system for the purpose of queries, as long as the local servers is connected to the remote server.

I highly suggest checking out the CIS documentation linked above, as there are some tutorials on setting it up.